# How to dynamically load OSGI fragment programmatically from within Java?

Tags: java, osgi

How can I load an OSGI fragment, along with all of the resources within its bundle (config files, etc), programmatically from Java?

I would like to access the resources via getResource() as if they were in the internal Jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need a handle to bundle context. From thereon you can listen to bundle references, there get a Bundle instance and use its classloader to do what you want.

Example that uses a Servlet to hook into bundle context and [ServiceTracker](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html) to listen for osgi bundles appearing

```
public class AnotherHelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private MessageService service = null;
  private BundleContext context;

  @Override
  public void init(final ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    context = (BundleContext) config.getServletContext().getAttribute("osgi-bundlecontext");

    final AnotherHelloWorldServlet servlet = this;

    ServiceTracker tracker = new ServiceTracker(context,
        MessageService.class.getName(), null) {

      @Override
      public Object addingService(final ServiceReference sref) {
        log.infof("Adding service: %s to %s", sref, servlet);
        service = (MessageService) super.addingService(sref);
        return service;
      }

      @Override
      public void removedService(final ServiceReference sref, final Object sinst) {
        super.removedService(sref, service);
        log.infof("Removing service: %s from %s", sref, servlet);
        service = null;
      }
    };
    tracker.open();
  }
}
```

with a ServiceReference you can call [getBundle()](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/ServiceReference.html#getBundle%28%29) to get a bundle instance, and for that, [getResource()](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to get what you asked for.

If you cannot use a servlet or similar (=if you are outside Java EE/servlet container), there aren't that many standard ways to hook into the bundle context that I know of. In that case you might need to resort to [BundleContextProvider hack](https://github.com/tdiesler/jbosgi/blob/d7caf3126fb35b823d083b238e7d974b06865396/testsuite/jbossas/api/src/main/java/org/jboss/test/osgi/jbossas/example/payment/BundleContextProvider.java) to get it.